# Google Guice + Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, guice

`Class A` depends on `class B`, `class B` depends on `class C`.

I'm trying to test `class A`, for this I create a `B-mock`, and bind it with `class B`:

```
injector =
     Guice.createInjector (
         new AbstractModule () {
             @Override
             protected void configure () {
                 bind(B.class).toInstance(Mockito.mock(B.class));
             }
         }
     );
```

It would seem that since `B` is a mock, then an object of `class C` is not needed either. But google guice is still trying to create it for some reason using `new`.
I know this because I put `System.out("C conctructor")` in the `C class` constructor, and I see this output in the tests.

One solution is to use its interface instead of `class C`. But this is strange behavior anyway.

How else can you get around this situation?

Comment: @Progman no, C does not just call the constructor, objects that do not work in the test environment are injected into C. For example, connecting to a database.
Because of this, the test does not work

Comment: I misread "depends on" as "extends from", my bad. Please [edit] your question to include the source code of your problem as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show that the constructor of `C` is called even thou it shouldn't be.